# Выполнить javascript функцию при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, функции

Извините за тупой вопрос, но все-же, есть файл явовский с функция, одна из них:

```
function DleTrackDownload( id ) {
    if ( $( '#dletrack-ajax-wrapper' ).css( 'display' ) != 'none' ) {
        if ( dletrack_last_ajax == 'download' ) {
            $( '#dletrack-ajax-wrapper' ).slideUp( 600 );
        } else {
            ShowLoading( '' );
            $.get( dle_root + 'engine/modules/dletrack/ajax/download.php', { track_id: id, dle_template: dle_skin }, function( response ) {
                HideLoading( '' );
                dletrack_last_ajax = 'download';
                $( '#dletrack-ajax-wrapper' ).slideUp( 300, function( ) {
                    $( '#dletrack-ajax-wrapper' ).html( response ).slideDown( 600 );
                });
            });
        }
    } else {
        ShowLoading( '' );
        $.get( dle_root + 'engine/modules/dletrack/ajax/download.php', { track_id: id, dle_template: dle_skin }, function( response ) {
            HideLoading( '' );
            dletrack_last_ajax = 'download';
            $( '#dletrack-ajax-wrapper' ).html( response ).slideDown( 600 );
        });
    }
}
```

На страницэ она вызывается кликом по ссылке

```
<a href="#" onclick="DleTrackDownload({track-id});return false;"><img src="{THEME}/dletrack/images/icon-save.png" alt="" /> <b>Ko'chirib olish КАПЧА</b></a>
<div id="dletrack-ajax-wrapper" style="margin-top:15px;display:none"></div>
```

как сделать выполение скрипта после загрузки страницы?
Пробовал так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
DleTrackDownload({track-id});
return false;
</script>
```

не помогло, пробовал удалить display:none из дива не помогло....

Comment: # Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутрь `DleTrackDownload` не заглядывал, но для автостарта можете использовать атрибут `onload`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function DleTrackDownload( id ) { ... }
            function init() {
                DleTrackDownload(...);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>//если используешь библиотеку      //jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//Здесь функция function DleTrackDownload

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

100% Вариант на чистом JavaScript:

```js
function initOnLoad(fn) {
  var readyState = document.readyState

  if(readyState === 'interactive' || readyState === 'complete') {
    return fn()
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn)
}

initOnLoad(function() {
  console.log('hello world!')
})
```

#### Объяснение

Сначала заносим текущий степень готовности DOM'а в переменную, далее проверяем можем ли мы уже взаимодействовать с DOM, если может, запускаем функцию и сразу возвращаем её. Если проверка не прошла, добавляем событие `DOMContentLoaded`, чтобы запустить функцию, когда DOM загрузится. В прошлом мы вернули функцию чтобы не добавлять события `DOMContentLoaded` (т.к. при возвращении чего-либо, последующий код не выполнится)