# Сделать чтобы скрипт выполнялся при загрузке страницы, а не каждую секунду?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы скрипт выполнялся при загрузке страницы, а не каждую секунду?

```
setInterval(detectTime, 1000);    
function detectTime(){
    let h = (new Date()).getHours();
    if(h >= 21 || h < 6) Night();
}
function Night(){
    console.log('Night');
}
```

Comment: Можно просто в коде поменять это `setInterval(detectTime, 1000);` на `detectTime()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнить javascript функцию при загрузке страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/335873/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-javascript-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: @SwaD Ваш ответ самый красивый. Напишите в ответы, отмечу.

Comment: @NowhereMan Не думаю что можно считать дубликатом. Одно из решений похоже, согласен. Но суть вопроса сильно отличается.

Comment: @Юра, вопрос вида "как вызвать скрипт при загрузке страницы" не может не иметь дубликатов в конце 2022 года, так как обработчик события `onload` один из самых древних

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
setInterval(detectTime, 1000);
```

Написать

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", detectTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов, вы можете поместить вашу функцию в body:

```
    <body onload="detectTime()">
```